# Neo4j allPaths giving performance issue

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal

I have used following code to get all paths between source and sink node

```
final PathFinder<Path> paths = GraphAlgoFactory.allPaths(expander, 20);
for (Path allPaths : paths.findAllPaths(source, target)) {
        list.add(allPaths);

}
return list;
```

But it is not returning response and it consuming huge memory and after some time servers is not responding to other threads. Please suggest batter cost effect query for these type graph traversal.

Comment: It would probably be good to add some information about the data set (how many relationships have to be traversed during a request?) and memory config etc.

Comment: it will be traverse nearly 28 relationships.Even as per requirement i did not control my depth.But for time being i have given 20 as max depth.

Comment: Why not try executing Cypher query using executionengine instead of using AlgoFactory?

Comment: jerry, I mean the total number of relationships traversed, not the depth.

Comment: nearly 25 relationships need to traverse.

Comment: 25 relationships to traverse in total for the whole operation? If that's the case, you created some endless loop in your code.

Comment: Please also share the expander code. And a graph model.